# MVC Html.TextBoxFor binding to something other than model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, ajax.beginform

I've got a base controller that is passing an object with properties into a ViewBag object on every view.  I was wondering, is it possible to bind an Html.EditorFor or Html.TextBoxFor to something other than my view's model object?  Essentially, the goal is a contact us form that is hidden in a modal on every page but I don't want to have to pass a new object into every View for that form.  I know it can be done using standard HTML/ajax (which is what I'm doing right now) but I'm just curious if it's even possible. Thanks in advance.

In my BaseController:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            ViewBag.ContactUs = new Model.ContactUs();
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

Then in my _Layout, I've got something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContactUs", "Contact", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
    {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(????=> ViewBag.ContactUs.FirstName) 
       <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    }
```

Jay